# Column Highlighting - Apply CSS to all <td> under a given <th>

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to apply this highlight class:

```
.highlight = { background-color: yellow }
```

to all **`<td>`** under a **`<th class = "sorting_desc">`** or **`<th class = "sorting_asc">`**

***Javascript solutions would be acceptable.***

Comment: Confuses me `which are below (in the selected column) `

Comment: @Mr Alien I think it means "highlight column"

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: can you provide your html structure atleast?

Comment: Can you change your HTML ? If yes, I would create a colgroup with cols, and set the class in the cols. I will give an answer if this is ok.

Comment: Yes, I can add colgroups, but the class names sorting_desc and sorting_asc are always applied to the th

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment and I post an answer. You should have included "@vals" in your comment :-). Disregard the css part of my answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is posible with CSS with your markup.

You can do it with Javascript:

```
function(){
    var thl=document.getElementsByTagName('th');
    var trl=document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var classname;
    for(var i=0;i<thl.length;i++)
    {
        var th=thl[i];
        if (th.className == 'sorting-desc') {
              classname = 'highlight';
        } else if (th.className == 'sorting-asc') {
              classname = 'highlight';  
        } else {
              classname = '';
        }

        for(var j=0;j<trl.length;j++)
        {
            var tr=trl[j];
            var td=tr.cells[i];
            if (td) {
                td.className=classname;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You get a list of headers and a list of rows. For every th in the header, you decide what class to apply, and you do a loop across the rows, seting the cell that matches the current column number to the class that you have decided.

Of course you can set the background color directly instead of setting a class.

**However** if you can change the HTML, what I **would** do is to set cols and the class that you want to the col:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="asc">A</th>
        <col class="desc">D</th>
        <col class="aasc">A</th>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
       <th>A</th>
       <th>D</th>
       <th>A</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>A</th>
       <td>D</th>
       <td>A</th>
    </tr>
```

This way both your th and td will have the correct class (asc or desc) applied

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/guf3p/)

Comment: Thanks for this vals, if you can please update your answer to reflect my class names above, I will provide you the tick.

Comment: I Have adapted the Javascript to your new requirements

Comment: Look, I'm not quite sure why this isn't working, but it isn't. Very frustrating. Did you get this working in a jsfiddle? If so, I'll tick it for you.. it might just be a wrapper or something created by the datatables plugin which is messing it up for me.

Comment: Added fiddle with your classes, just click anywhere in the table

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `td` as a child of `th`, you can markup your table like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And style your `td` or `th`:

```
#mytable th { background: red; }
#mytable td { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: I realize the problem of not having a td as a child of th.. this is my struggle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**CSS**

```
.bg-highlight{background:yellow;}
.bg-columns{color:red;}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var th=document.getElementsByTagName('th')[0];
var td=th.getElementsByTagName('td');
th.className='bg-highlight';
for(var i=0;i<td.length;i++)
{
    td[i].style.background='red';
    // Or try applying classes in it
    //td[i].className='bg-columns';
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please include my classes in this ?

Comment: Test the above answer I've made changes in it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand .. I want highlight a column based on the class of the <th>

Comment: when things are getting complicated (classes), jquery is the way @Abram

Comment: My target classes are sorting_desc and sorting_asc